# Remove "virtual" volumes from macOS Catalina after Big Sur beta?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I have played around with macOS Big Sur for a few weeks but I decided to downgrade to Catalina. Big Sur handles volumes a bit differently and creates a  virtual `volume - Data` volume. The interesting part that this multiple virtual volumes situation stays after the downgrade too, and now I have 2 similarly named volume (*MacBookPro*) and an *Update* volume which seemingly another virtual one).

How can I remove/merge this virtual volumes? It is really annoying for multiple reasons but the most porblematic is that Time Machine couldn't backup because of the 2 volumes have the same name.

(My MacBook has only 128GB SSD)

[image]

Comment: @dan First I installed Big Sur on top of Catalina and then format the whole drive from recovery and reinstalled BigSur since I wanted a clean install. To downgrade I formated the (multiple) volumes (the above mentioned 3 was there already) and installed Catalina via internet recovery. When the installer asked I just randomly selected one of the 2 similarly named volume.

Comment: Please improve your original question to get correct answers. This was the purpose of my previous comment. Comments usually don’t stay their purpose being to help improve questions.